# Xamarin Forms Android Activity Bundle is null

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a secondary activity from a service in my Xamarin Forms Android App.  The activity seems to start just fine.  Buit I need to pass some data along to it, but the OnCreate method parameter Bundle is always null.

From a page in my PCL project, the service is being called:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    ISampleService service = DependencyService.Get<ISampleService>();
    service.ProcessSampleData(6);
}
```

The android service:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SampleService))]

namespace ServiceActivityTester.Droid
{
    [Service]
    public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        public bool ProcessSampleData(int sampleData)
        {
            Context context = MainActivity.Instance;
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                context, typeof(SampleActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("SampleData", sampleData);

            activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            // context.StartActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The secondary activity:

```
namespace ServiceActivityTester.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SampleActivity")]
    public class SampleActivity
        : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // savedInstanceState == null always!
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            int sampleData = savedInstanceState.GetInt("SampleData");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sampleData.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

My manifest file is the same as it was upon creation.

**How can I get the Bundle data to be not null (So, I can retrieve the SampleData putExtra data)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the `Intent` property to get the parameters passed to the `Activity`.

something like:

```
int sampleData = Intent.GetIntExtra("SampleData", 0);
```

Where `0` will be the default value you want for your property in case the value is not found in the Intent.

Note: **savedInstanceState** is used to get the saved values from previous states, if you did save them.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for! Also, I never knew that the Bundle is from previous states, but looking at the parameter name, it makes sense.